# Edges of ShapeDrawable oval (stroke-style) are cut (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable, android-paint

I'm new to Android Studio and at the moment I'm trying to create an oval (not solid, just stroke) of random color, stroke width and size programmatically:

```
        long randomSeedm = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(randomSeedm);
        int[] color = {R.color.red, R.color.black, .....};

        int ovalWidth = 20 + random.nextInt(100);
        int ovalHeight = 20 + random.nextInt(100);

        ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        shape.setIntrinsicWidth (ovalWidth);
        shape.setIntrinsicHeight (ovalHeight);
        shape.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(color[random.nextInt(6)]));
        shape.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        shape.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(2+random.nextInt(15));
        shape.getPaint().setAntiAlias(true);

        ImageView oval = new ImageView(this);
        oval.setImageDrawable(shape);
```

Ater that I put the ImageView into a FrameLayout that covers the whole screen:

```
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
        left = random.nextInt(frameLayoutWidth - ovalWidth);
        top = random.nextInt(frameLayoutHeight - ovalHeight);
        params.leftMargin = left;
        params.topMargin = top;
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP + Gravity.LEFT;

        frameLayoutWholeScreen.addView(oval, params);
```

The results are very satisfying (from my beginner's point of view), the only problem is that the edges of the ovals are partially cut. Here are some examples:

Example 1

[image: [1]]

Example 2

[image: [2]]

Is there some way to avoid the cuts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the value of the stroke when making the frame layout params.

```
    int strokeSize = 2 + random.nextInt(15);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ovalWidth + strokeSize, ovalHeight + strokeSize);
    left = random.nextInt(frameLayoutWidth - (ovalWidth + strokeSize));
    top = random.nextInt(frameLayoutHeight - (ovalHeight + strokeSize));
    params.leftMargin = left;
    params.topMargin = top;
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP + Gravity.LEFT;
    frameLayoutWholeScreen.addView(oval, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

We still have this issue with Paint.

From what I analysed, it seems that the paint is trying to draw the stroke at the edge of the view(i.e start, end, top or bottom), having the edge(or the respective start, end, top or bottom points) as stoke's midpoint which results in displaying only the half of the stroke and the other half of the stroke's width is drawn outside the view. This may or may not be wrong.

Solution: Try not to draw the paint at the edges(i.e start, end, top or bottom) exactly. Reduce the size of the endpoints.

Changing the endpoints like the following worked for me: start + (1.dpToPx), top + (1.dpToPx), bottom - (1.dpToPx), end - (1.dpToPx).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).